# How can I read and write data from footer of Excel file by Blue prism?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I don't know how to read and write data from footer of Excel file? can somebody please guide me ?

Regards,

Adnan

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried a code stage and but it is also not working.

Comment: read and write stage will not work on it

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using send keys? It was the only way i could find of writing to a header/ footer as a write stage does not seem to work on it. Another alternative for me was using the 'insert file name' button.

Comment: Hi but Global send keys wont work because my application will not be actively running. therefore cannot use i want without Workbook show its should read data from excel footer.